Is it possible to use udf with SORT BY in azure cosmos db query definition?
I am trying to extend sorting functionality of ORDER BY by using udf. I have created and registered a small udf, which always returns 0, to test it.
Here is my query:
SELECT *
FROM c
ORDER BY udf.sortPosts(c) ASC

but i get an error:
"code":"BadRequest","message":"One of the input values is invalid.
So the question is is it even possible to use udf with order by, or there is an error on my side?
I have tried running a query without calling a udf and sorting by a field, and it works correctly.
udf i tried with:
function sortPosts(posts){
    return 0;
}


You're attempting to use sortPosts() as a property. A UDF doesn't return a property; it returns a value. And ORDER BY works by evaluating values of a given property/properties (the exact wording of the docs: "Specifies a property or expression on which to sort the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or property alias") - you don't pass specific values to ORDER BY. This is why you're getting your error, as it's invalid syntax.

@DavidMakogon thank you! I guess the only possible way to sort than is to use stored procedure?


Is it possible to use udf with SORT BY in azure cosmos db query definition?

Yes, it is possible to use udf with SORT BY in Cosmos DB Query. As David mentioned there is a syntax error in the query, Below is an example with sample data with correct syntax.
SELECT udf.sortByRanks(c) FROM c ORDER  BY c.rank  DESC

UDF I tried:
function sortByRanks(items) {
    for (let i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
        let j = i - 1;
        let temp = items[i];
        while (j >= 0 && items[j].rank > temp.rank) {
            items[j + 1] = items[j];
            j--;
        }
        items[j + 1] = temp;
    }
    return items;
}

Output:
[
    {
        "$1": {
            "id": "5",
            "studentId": "1005",
            "name": "Mike",
            "age": 26,
            "rank": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "$1": {
            "id": "4",
            "studentId": "1004",
            "name": "John",
            "age": 24,
            "rank": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "$1": {
            "id": "3",
            "studentId": "1003",
            "name": "Paul",
            "age": 22,
            "rank": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "$1": {
            "id": "2",
            "studentId": "1002",
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 21,
            "rank": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "$1": {
            "id": "1",
            "studentId": "1001",
            "name": "Alice",
            "age": 20,
            "rank": 1
        }
    }
]

Check this document for more information on ORDER BY.
